# How to fix tinymce error for multi line text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am working with ASP.NET WebForm
I have some problems with tinymce and multi line text boxes . 
when I click on Submit button, I faced with error. 
I have used from some trikes like: `OnClientClick="tinyMCE.triggerSave(false,true);"`
but it doesn't work . 
Please show me some solution.

```
 <div style="float: left; width: 100px;">
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" Text="<%$Resources:Buttons,Submit %>"
            OnClientClick="tinyMCE.triggerSave(false,true);" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />

    </div>


<script src="../Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    tinyMCE.init({
        selector: "textarea",
         height: 500,
        plugins: [
          "advlist autolink autosave link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
          "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
          "table contextmenu directionality emoticons template textcolor paste fullpage textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
        ],

        toolbar1: "newdocument fullpage | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | styleselect formatselect fontselect fontsizeselect",
        toolbar2: "cut copy paste | searchreplace | bullist numlist | outdent indent blockquote | undo redo | link unlink anchor image media code | insertdatetime preview | forecolor backcolor",
        toolbar3: "table | hr removeformat | subscript superscript | charmap emoticons | print fullscreen | ltr rtl | spellchecker | visualchars visualblocks nonbreaking template pagebreak restoredraft",

        menubar: false,
        toolbar_items_size: 'small',

        style_formats: [{
            title: 'Bold text',
            inline: 'b'
        }, {
            title: 'Red text',
            inline: 'span',
            styles: {
                color: '#ff0000'
            }
        }, {
            title: 'Red header',
            block: 'h1',
            styles: {
                color: '#ff0000'
            }
        }, {
            title: 'Example 1',
            inline: 'span',
            classes: 'example1'
        }, {
            title: 'Example 2',
            inline: 'span',
            classes: 'example2'
        }, {
            title: 'Table styles'
        }, {
            title: 'Table row 1',
            selector: 'tr',
            classes: 'tablerow1'
        }],

        templates: [{
            title: 'Test template 1',
            content: 'Test 1'
        }, {
            title: 'Test template 2',
            content: 'Test 2'
        }],
        content_css: [
          '//fast.fonts.net/cssapi/e6dc9b99-64fe-4292-ad98-6974f93cd2a2.css',
          '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
        ]
    });
```

Comment: Can you edit the post with the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are facing with the validation problem which occurs when TinyMCE used with ASP.NET Web Forms. I ended up with the following solution for my own project.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    setup: function (editor) {          
        // Listen to change and keyup events and trigger save event
        editor.on('change', tinyMCE.triggerSave);
        editor.on('keyup', tinyMCE.triggerSave);
    },
    ... // Other options
});
```

Comment: Thank you because of your guidance . But unfortunately it still does't work.

Comment: Mr Izzet , If you have any other idea or solution please tell me .

Comment: Is it still showing a validation error? I wrote whole code here in the editor so there may be an error in the code. Are you sure did it work correctly and you are still having the problem?

Comment: I have tried lots of different ways. but still problem exist . 
when I omit scrip files . text box work correctly , but as soon as I use from scripts , error appears again! ( so funny so annoying )

Comment: Please add a screenshot to your question. Everything will be much clear.

Comment: Actually I replaced tinymce with Check Editor . and this one work very well. they have designed Check Editor for asp.net and by adding dll file to the project you can enjoy from this awesome tool .

Again, thank you because of your contribution .